# Why can I not use Asp.Net DataAnnotation Validation with VS 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem. I am developing Asp.Net MVC2 Application with VS2008 very well, but now I want to use the amazing DataAnnotion Validation shipping with Microsoft.MVC.DataAnnotation.dll. I can't find the DLL so I found it on the project Site @ http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471#DownloadId=61772

I can't compile the Project. Is it a VS 2010 or .Net 4.0 thing ? Do I need VS 2010 or is there a way to use it within VS2008 ?

Thanks a lot guys, sorry about my bad English ;)

Comment: your link points to mvc1 sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VS2010, you can use Data Annotations with VS2008 and .net 3.5

The example above actually works in VS2008. I just verified it.

Also the dll you mentioned above is the wrong dll for MVC2, instead of Microsoft.MVC.DataAnnotation.dll, you want  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations which should be part of .net 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

follow this guide: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx

maybe you just need to service pack your vs